# Puppeteer: is there any way to get all eventListeners for page.on()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, event-handling, puppeteer

For example,

```
page.on('response', doSomthingOnResponse1);
page.on('response', doSometingOnResponse2);
```

I want to get all eventListeners for `response` event

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As `Page` is an `EventEmitter`, you should be able to call the [listeners](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_listeners_eventname) function.

```js
const functions = page.listeners('response');
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: page.listeners is not a function` :/ I can call method `on` though

Comment: @AlexanderKondaurov Puppeteer needs to update to Mitt 2.1 to support a similar feature.

Comment: I use version 5.1.0, it depends on Mitt 2.1 but method 'listeners' doesn't exist. `Page` is NOT nodejs `EventEmitter`, there is breaking change since 4.0.0: "As part of our work to make Puppeteer agnostic of its environment we are removing the dependency on Node’s EventEmitter in favour of an event emitter that is not tied to Node"